# Pyinstaller win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'System cannot access the file')

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to use the pyinstaller to pack my python file in to .exe, but I keep getting this error message.

```
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'System can not access the file')
```

I've tried running the cmd as administrator but it's still not working.

My operating system is Windows 10

Comment: Please show the FULL stacktrace and other outputs of PyInstaller.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to solve the same problem by uninstalling python (installed from Microsoft store) and installing 3.8.2 from [python.org](https://python.org).

Answer (score 3):

I think there's an access permission problem with windows, specifically with `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` folder (it's hidden).

I created a virtual environment, installed pyinstaller within the venv, and everything worked fine.

Comment: The best solution! It's working with venv and python from microsoft store perfectly! But I had to install one packet from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65569809/8962418

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Just move your python file in your `C:\Users\batman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts` folder where you can also find `pyinstaller.exe` and run the windows command prompt there and try again!

Answer (score 2):

Update your Python version.
I updated mine form Python 3.7.6 to Python 3.8.2 on https://www.python.org/downloads/
I just did it and it worked for me!

Comment: Could you point out exactly to which Python version you've updated? This way you'll be more specific in helping the users.

Answer (score 1):

I've been coming back to this problem now for months after my new PC had this idea. After selling my laptop (that pyinstaller worked on), I was forced to find a solution. To try and figure out what was going on I created a virtual environment in pycharm and it suddenly worked. I'd recommend giving pycharm a go!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the issue is apparently that Windows does not like `pyinstaller` to be run under `C:\Users\`. I was having the same issue and I moved my python scripts under `C:\Temp` where I could run `pyinstaller` without issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have to uninstall your current python and reinstall it again. The reason is that either you have a 32 bit python or some file(s) of the your python are corrupted, thus you have to reinstall all the libraries again.

Answer (score 0):

If you've built your Python project in `PyCharm`, and later installed `pyinstaller`, there is a copy of the `pyinstaller` program EXE in the Output subfolders.

Simple copy the **full path** of where the `pyInstaller.exe` is located inside your PyCharm project, open `CMD` as Administrator, go to your PyCharm project folder, where your `.py` file is located and paste the path copied earlier (windows 10), plus add the `pyInstaller.exe` extension.

i.e.

```
C:\Users\<<YOUR USER FOLDER>>\<<YOUR PYCHARM PROJECT>>\output\pyInstaller.exe <<YOUR python FILE>>
```

It will compile.