# Error when running pyinstaller (1920, 'LoadLibraryEx', 'System cannot access the file')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Im trying to compile my python script to an exe so that i can send it to friends that can use with without having to install python, but im running into an issue and cant find a solution.

i found a similar issue at [Pyinstaller win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'System cannot access the file')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57180580/pyinstaller-win32ctypes-pywin32-pywintypes-error-1920-loadlibraryexw-syst)

but cant post there except as a answer, i tried to add permissions and unhide the 'WindowsApps' folder but nothing seems to work.

Here is what cmd is giving me when running pyinstaller

and 'Systemet kan inte komma åt filen' is swedish for 'System cannot access the file'

```
100 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
101 INFO: Python: 3.7.4
101 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
103 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Jonathan\Pictures\shimbot2\gui.spec
106 INFO: UPX is not available.
109 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\Pictures', 'C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\Pictures\\shimbot2']
110 INFO: checking Analysis
110 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
111 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
116 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
119 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
4140 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
    return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_dll.py", line 26, in _LoadLibraryEx
    function_name='LoadLibraryEx')
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 81, in __call__
    self._raise_error(function_name)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 92, in _raise_error
    raise exception
OSError: [WinError 1920] Systemet kan inte komma åt filen

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Pictures\shimbot2\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Pictures\shimbot2\gui.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 243, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 405, in assemble
    redirects=self.binding_redirects)[1:])
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 231, in Dependencies
    for ftocnm, fn in getAssemblyFiles(pth, manifest, redirects):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 407, in getAssemblyFiles
    for assembly in getAssemblies(pth):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 358, in getAssemblies
    res = GetManifestResources(pth)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 1005, in GetManifestResources
    return winresource.GetResources(filename, [RT_MANIFEST], names, languages)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 168, in GetResources
    hsrc = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(filename, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
    return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
    raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryEx', 'Systemet kan inte komma åt filen')
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: After extensive trial and error i just gave up for now and had my friends install python and the modules required (i whipped up a quick batchfile)

Answer (score 4):

We don't support the Windows store version of python due to the fact that PyInstaller can't access the DLLs required to build you application. Please use a virtual environment of some kind or install python from https://python.org

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with this, apparently it's something to do with shared file systems.

The solution in the post you provided helped me sort the problem, follow this link to guide you to create a virtual environment:

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-virtual-environment/amp/

If you have any issues with pyinstaller not being 'recognised as an internal or external command' dont forget to add the virtual environment pyinstaller module to your environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same '(1920, 'LoadLibraryEx', 'System cannot access the file')'  problem with Pyinstaller and after much thrashing on the problem decided to clean up my Python environment.  So I uninstalled Python 3.6 and 3.7 then uninstalled PyCharm and Anaconda.

Then installed Python 3.8 and Pip 3.8 and then Pyinstaller and IT WORKED!!!  My hunch is the problem was a conflict between 3.6 and 3.7 but that is just a hunch.  I do think PyCharm and Anaconda are great products - - I'm just going to be WAY more careful about my Python environment from here on out.

[BTW Pyinstaller worked flawlessly first time on my Linux development box.]