# Unable to convert py files to exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to convert my python program to a standalone executable file. However, after running pyinstaller, it runs into an error and doesn't output the file. This is the log:

```
60 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
60 INFO: Python: 3.8.3
60 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
61 INFO: wrote C:\Users\username\Downloads\pip\test.spec
63 INFO: UPX is not available.
64 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\pip', 'C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\pip']
64 INFO: checking Analysis
65 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
65 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
67 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
71 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
1900 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
1900 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib'
3116 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
3200 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
    yield
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
    return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_dll.py", line 23, in _LoadLibraryEx
    result = check_null(
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 81, in __call__
    self._raise_error(function_name)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 92, in _raise_error
    raise exception
OSError: [WinError 1920] The file cannot be accessed by the system

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 681, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\username\Downloads\pip\test.spec", line 6, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['test.py'],
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 393, in assemble
    self.binaries.extend(bindepend.Dependencies([('', python, '')],
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 228, in Dependencies
    for ftocnm, fn in getAssemblyFiles(pth, manifest, redirects):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 404, in getAssemblyFiles
    for assembly in getAssemblies(pth):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 355, in getAssemblies
    res = GetManifestResources(pth)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 1007, in GetManifestResources
    return winresource.GetResources(filename, [RT_MANIFEST], names, languages)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 170, in GetResources
    hsrc = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(filename, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
    return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
    raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryEx', 'The file cannot be accessed by the system')
```

I also tried using **brentvollebregt**'s **auto-py-to-exe** but ran into the same error.

Does it have to do with admin rights? Do I have to run command prompt as an admin in order to use pyinstaller? Or do I have to be logged-in as the admin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

Answer (score 0):

Please use google before posting a question on stackoverflow, this is the original question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60320831/12533273

You may have two versions of python3 installed and that's cousing a problem, try uninstalling all versions of python and then reinstalling them.

Comment: Went to the link you provided, but I'm positive I only have one version of python3. I've uninstalled multiple times already. I've tried using a virtual environment and yet received the ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''``` error.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, can you edit the post so that it includes the new error.

Answer (score -1):

```
.\pyinstaller --onefile -w 'filename.py'
```

or

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w 'filename.py'
```

use the above two commands in the powershell while you went to the page of conversion should be made.

> https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200202204743/Screenshot-5013.png