# Can't launch pyinstaller after downloading it on windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, environment-variables, pyinstaller

I downloaded pyinstaller using pip3, but at the end of the download I got this message :

```
  WARNING: The scripts pyi-archive_viewer.exe, pyi-bindepend.exe, pyi-grab_version.exe, pyi-makespec.exe, pyi-set_version.exe and pyinstaller.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\panyc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

I then added the path to my environment variable, but nothing changed, I still have this message.
How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:
`python -m pyinstaller <parameters>`
If this doesn't work, try this:
`python -m PyInstaller <parameters>`
Note: on some systems, `python` is `python3`.

Comment: I tried both, but its not working, I'm getting this error : win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryEx', 'The file cannot be accessed by the system')

Comment: That's a problem out of this question.  See this: [Pyinstaller win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'System cannot access the file')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57180580/pyinstaller-win32ctypes-pywin32-pywintypes-error-1920-loadlibraryexw-syst)