# why is pyinstaller not working on python 3.9.0, it gives the following error:

Tags: python

107 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0
108 INFO: Python: 3.8.6
108 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
109 INFO: wrote C:\Users\andreiz\Desktop\Alogirthm\algoritm.spec
114 INFO: UPX is not available.
116 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\Users\andreiz\Desktop\Alogirthm',
'C:\Users\andreiz\Desktop\Alogirthm']
129 INFO: checking Analysis
129 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
129 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
134 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
158 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3141 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_find_module_path\hook-distutils.py'.
3143 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib'
4834 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
4980 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
yield
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi_dll.py", line 23, in _LoadLibraryEx
result = check_null(
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi_util.py", line 81, in **call**
self._raise_error(function_name)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi_util.py", line 92, in _raise_error
raise exception
OSError: [WinError 1920] The file cannot be accessed by the system

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in *run_module_as_main
return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe_*main**.py", line 7, in 
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py", line 114, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py", line 65, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 720, in main
build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 667, in build
exec(code, spec_namespace)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\Desktop\Alogirthm\algoritm.spec", line 6, in 
a = Analysis(['algoritm.py'],
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in **init**
self.**postinit**()
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in **postinit**
self.assemble()
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 390, in assemble
self.binaries.extend(bindepend.Dependencies([('', python, '')],
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 228, in Dependencies
for ftocnm, fn in getAssemblyFiles(pth, manifest, redirects):
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 407, in getAssemblyFiles
for assembly in getAssemblies(pth):
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 358, in getAssemblies
res = GetManifestResources(pth)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 1000, in GetManifestResources
return winresource.GetResources(filename, [RT_MANIFEST], names, languages)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 170, in GetResources
hsrc = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(filename, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in **exit**
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryEx', 'The file cannot be accessed by the system')
107 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0
108 INFO: Python: 3.8.6
108 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
109 INFO: wrote C:\Users\andreiz\Desktop\Alogirthm\algoritm.spec
114 INFO: UPX is not available.
116 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\Users\andreiz\Desktop\Alogirthm',
'C:\Users\andreiz\Desktop\Alogirthm']
129 INFO: checking Analysis
129 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
129 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
134 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
158 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3141 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_find_module_path\hook-distutils.py'.
3143 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib'
4834 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
4980 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
yield
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi_dll.py", line 23, in _LoadLibraryEx
result = check_null(
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi_util.py", line 81, in **call**
self._raise_error(function_name)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi_util.py", line 92, in _raise_error
raise exception
OSError: [WinError 1920] The file cannot be accessed by the system

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in *run_module_as_main
return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe_*main**.py", line 7, in 
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py", line 114, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main**.py", line 65, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 720, in main
build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 667, in build
exec(code, spec_namespace)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\Desktop\Alogirthm\algoritm.spec", line 6, in 
a = Analysis(['algoritm.py'],
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in **init**
self.**postinit**()
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in **postinit**
self.assemble()
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 390, in assemble
self.binaries.extend(bindepend.Dependencies([('', python, '')],
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 228, in Dependencies
for ftocnm, fn in getAssemblyFiles(pth, manifest, redirects):
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 407, in getAssemblyFiles
for assembly in getAssemblies(pth):
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 358, in getAssemblies
res = GetManifestResources(pth)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 1000, in GetManifestResources
return winresource.GetResources(filename, [RT_MANIFEST], names, languages)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 170, in GetResources
hsrc = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(filename, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in **exit**
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
File "C:\Users\andreiz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryEx', 'The file cannot be accessed by the system')

Comment: please reformat your error output according to [formatting recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: I think this is the duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57180580/pyinstaller-win32ctypes-pywin32-pywintypes-error-1920-loadlibraryexw-syst

Comment: question says its python 3.9 but everywhere in the error it only says python 3.8?

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue.
For me it was due to the Path variable not being assigned.

you have to modify your PATH environment to include C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>

here's how to do it;
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html