# getting os error python library not found

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyinstaller

I installed python3.9 on windows 10. I created a virtual environment and installed all the packages i need for my program I then ran pyinstaller to create an executable and got the following error message: OSError: Python library not found: libpython39m.dll, python39.dll, libpython39.dll, libpython3.9.dll, libpython3.9m.dll

Do I need to install python to my virtual environment folder? I looked at other questions that are similar but didn't understand the solutions. I am very new creating exes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some problems with dependencies and PyInstaller some time ago, I solved it by installing Python 3.8.6 and PyInstaller through:

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
python.exe -m pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```

Comment: i ran those two lines and then tried running pyinstaller again i got the same error

Comment: What version of PyInstaller are you using? did you uninstall PyInstaller before running these two lines above?

Comment: I am running Pyinstaller 4.1. I did not uninstall Pyinstaller first should i have?

Comment: uninstalled pyinstaller then ran the second line again still getting the same error. the first line just updates the pip right do i have to download python 3.8.6 first? I'll go ahead and get python 3.8.6

Comment: okay after uninstalling python and restarting using the two lines above worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same issue recently, managed to get it working with the following steps:

1 - Make sure you remove all installations of python you have installed over the windows AppStore and reinstall from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

2 - **[ IMPORTANT - but an easy step to slip ]** delete the virtual environment made with your previous python installation and re-install it (with all the required packages)

3 - create a new virtual env and install pyinstaller following -GConelhero's answer