# OSError when trying to use a C-based library in Python with ctypes (Windows)

Tags: python, c, windows, dll, ctypes

I'm currently trying to use a library written in C with my Python code but I didn't have much success at all. I'm currently using Windows and have downloaded, saved and installed the library (linked below) to a directory near my project using Cygwin.

As of now, I'm not sure how you load it within your Python code. I followed the instruction in this link: https://github.com/xiph/rnnoise/issues/69 but replaced the library path with a relative path and saved the library inside my project directory. Here's my code and here's the return error

```
import wave
import os,sys
import ctypes
import contextlib
import numpy as np
from ctypes import util
from scipy.io import wavfile
from pydub import AudioSegment

lib_path = "rnnoise"

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path)
```

Here's the version from the instruction:

```
import wave
import os,sys
import ctypes
import contextlib
import numpy as np
from ctypes import util
from scipy.io import wavfile
from pydub import AudioSegment

lib_path = util.find_library("rnnoise")
if (not("/" in lib_path)):
    lib_path = (os.popen('ldconfig -p | grep '+lib_path).read().split('\n')[0].strip().split(" ")[-1] or ("/usr/local/lib/"+lib_path))

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/duyba/Documents/CET/Project/vadtest/noisetest.py", line 14, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path)
  File "C:\Users\duyba\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 459, in LoadLibrary      
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\duyba\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 381, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 1920] The file cannot be accessed by the system
```

My impression of the instruction version was that they are trying to locate the library in Linux, so I just copied the library to the project folder and didn't know what they are trying to load once the library is located. Also, I think that some environment pathway problems may be at play here since I downloaded and installed this library in Windows.

The library: https://github.com/xiph/rnnoise.

Thanks.

Comment: What Is that file that you try to load ? At 1st glance, it looks like that is for *Nix*.

Comment: That's my problem here too: I'm not sure what file I'm trying to load. I just updated the question with the version from the instruction. Basically, my impression of the code was that they just tried to locate the library but I don' know what exactly what they are trying to load once it is found. @CristiFati

Answer (score 0):

This could be an file access permission error. You might be able to get around it by making a new virtual environment or by uninstalling and reinstalling Python; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57180580/pyinstaller-win32ctypes-pywin32-pywintypes-error-1920-loadlibraryexw-syst).